# Listview DataTemplate inter UserControl unable to binding

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding, user-controls, datatemplate

I have this problem:

I have a `ListView` control in the form. There is a `CustomControl` in the `DataTemplate` of this `ListView`. I want this custom control to be bound to the Time property in the ViewModel of the current form, but it cannot be bound, but the `DataTemplate` Other controls in the middle can be bound, what is going on? I will be very grateful

Here is my window:

```
    <ListView Grid.Row="2" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding PlanRotation}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="20 0 0 0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="时间：" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <TimeControl:DateTimePicker  Tag="{Binding ElementName=myWin,Path=DataContext.Time,Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                                                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                 Height="28"
                                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                 Width="152" 
                                                 Foreground="White"
                                                 BorderThickness="1"
                                                 BorderBrush="#FFABADB3" 
                                                 Background="Black" 
                                                 Grid.Column="1"/>                     

                    <ComboBox Text="{Binding ElementName=myWin,Path=DataContext.Scenes,Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                              VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                              Width="80" 
                              Height="21">                       
                    </ComboBox>
```

Here is my CustomControl `TimeControl:DateTimePicker` code:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="ManagementProject.UserControls.TimeControl.DateTimePicker"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ManagementProject.UserControls.TimeControl"
         xmlns:myTime="clr-namespace:ManagementProject.UserControls.TimeControl"
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="25" 
         d:DesignWidth="150" 
         Width="150"
         MaxHeight="25"
         x:Name="dtpName"
         Loaded="UserControl_Loaded" Tag="{Binding ElementName=textBlock1, Path=Text}">
           <TextBox 
        Height="23" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Text="{Binding ElementName=dtpName,Path=Tag,Mode=OneWayToSource,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        Margin="4,3,0,0" 
        Name="textBlock1"  
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="123" Foreground="White" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" SelectionBrush="{x:Null}" Style="{DynamicResource TextBoxStyle1}" />
```

My Custom control's `TextBox`'s Text is assignment in the background.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "cannot be bound"? Have you tried [debugging](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/debugging/) the binding?

Comment: sorry my english is poor，It means that it unable to bind to the Time property of the current Window's ViewMode.I am trying Debug binding but it has not been resolved yet.

Comment: What I meant was how do you come to the conclusion that it doesn't work? Which effect would you expect? Can you share the debug output?

Comment: I expect to get the Tag value of the custom control DateTimePicker in the DataTemplate of the ListView in the form, so that I can assign the value of the ViewModel to the Time. My Tag value is binding to Time. Can you understand this? I can get the value of this binding of the ComboBox control of my DataTemplate, but the Tag value of the custom control is always null.

Comment: This is my custom control DateTimePicker's Tag="{Binding ElementName=textBlock1, Path=Text}"
the next is custom control DateTimePicker's
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=dtpName,Path=Tag,Mode=OneWayToSource,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"" />
The value of the Text property of my TextBox is assigned from the background. then,the Text property of my TextBox binding the Tag,here is a bit around, can you understand?

Comment: I debugged it and found no exception information.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but it seems overly complicated to me. Especially the excessive use of OneWayToSource bindings shouldn't be necessary.

The Tag of the Control is bound to the Text of the TextBox, and the Text of the TextBox is bound to the Tag of the Control - how is this supposed to work?

Also I think you should add your own DependencyProperties to your DateTimePicker control, so you don't have use the Tag property.

Comment: @DanielSklenitzka,okay,thank you.I I tried adding an DependencyProperties，It stills not working，after I try to in my custom control DateTimePicker's Text="{Binding Path=PRTime,Mode=OneWayToSource,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}". The PRTime is one of Attributes of PlanRotation.The PlanRotation is my ListView'Item Source,The ItemsSource="{Binding PlanRotation}" ，now The program can be binding.Thank your help,have a good time heihei~~.

Comment: Having the same UWP issue with a Listview and a Textblock on a user control. The bindings are working but the data never displays for these controls in the user control. Have thrown everything at it with no luck. The controls, the binding process, template, code, etc., is exactly the same as the controls on the main page, (virtual duplicate Listview). It works just fine on the main form. About to give up and just not use the user control.

Answer (score 0):

I could only get straight up binding to work with a user control when it initialized. I ended up created a dependency property to be able to update the user control from outside it.

```
internal List<User> ContactlistContainer
        {
            get => (List<User>)GetValue(ContactlistContainerProperty);
            set => SetValue(ContactlistContainerProperty, value);
        }

internal static readonly DependencyProperty ContactlistContainerProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("ContactlistContainerProperty", typeof(List<User>), typeof(User), new PropertyMetadata(new List<User>()));
```